# How to correctly add and use Objection.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I am trying to add Objection.js to my project ([using ES6](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field) `"type": "module"`), and getting this error which points to `./models/user.js`:

```js
import { Model } from "objection";
         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'objection' does not provide an export named 'Model'
```

Using the following  code:

***./methods.js***

```js
import User from "./models/user.js";

async function getInfo(idnum) {
  const someUser = await User.query().findById(idnum);
  return someUser;
}
```

***./models/user.js***

```js
import db from "../connection.js";
import { Model } from "objection";

Model.knex(db);

class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }
}

export default User;
```

***./connection.js***

```js
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

import knexfile from "../knexfile.js";
const connection = knexfile[environment];

import knex from "knex";
const db = knex(connection);

export default db;
```

**UPDATE**
The [creator of Objection.js said](https://gitter.im/Vincit/objection.js?at=5ea708cff6a6e539797dcd99) `import { Model } from "objection"` should work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try objection module with require keyword. Objection.js is not a Common JS module I think

Comment: @Owner the rest of the project is ES6 modules so it would break.

Comment: Mostly, using import statements you can use experimental modules. I don't think Objection module is experimental. If you are using ES6, my recommendation would be to have require statements. @Raj: check this out https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c

Comment: Why do you think the code will break?

Comment: @Owner `ReferenceError: require is not defined` because I have `"type":"module"` in my package.json (and I can't remove it from my package.json because the rest of the project uses imports.

Comment: Its an optional parameter, "type" can have "commonjs" as well.

Comment: You can also downgrade your node version. Not every node module is supported in Node 14+ versions. Many of them are being deprecated.

Comment: @Owner if I switch to `"type":"commonjs"` then I can't use `import x from "y"`, which is what every file in my project currently uses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212615/discussion-between-owner-and-raj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only current workaround appears to be importing the `Model` like this:

```js
import objection from "objection";
const { Model } = objection;
```

since Objection.js does exports like this:

```js
export default { Model }
```

and not like this:

```js
export { Model }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you are using a .mjs extension for the file if you are using `import` in a Node app.

But if you are using a .js as extension then you have to call that module using `require`.

```js
const { Model } = require('objection');
```

This was the problem I once had... I don't know if this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm using `"type":"module"` for native ES6 support (albeit experimental): https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field so no I can't use `require` afaik